# Getting h1 from markdown via python's pandoc library

Tags: python, markdown, pandoc

I'm writing a python batch script to process many markdown files to get h1-like text to generate 'title' metadata variable (I forgot to add 'title' into frontmatter). I'm not using this as pandoc filter.

Thus I was thinking to process those files via pandoc-python, but I'm not familiar with that and I cannot figure out how to get only h1.

```
content = pandoc.read(post.content)
```

'content' is pandoc native format. And I see something like this

```
(Pdb) content                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Pandoc(Meta({}), [Header(1, ('foobar', [], []), [Str('foobar:')]), Para(...
```

I would like to get h1 as simple text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following snippet that works for headers both with `#` or `=======`.

```py
import pandoc
from pandoc.types import *

with open('README.md') as f:
    content = pandoc.read(f.read()) 
# But you can use your content.
headers = []

for elt in pandoc.iter(content):
     if isinstance(elt, Header):
         if elt[0] == 1: # this is header 1, remove this if statement if you want all headers.
             headers.append(elt[1][0])
```

Or if you want the exact string with upper case etc.:

```
for elt in pandoc.iter(content):
    if isinstance(elt, Header):
        if elt[0] == 1: # this is header 1, remove this if statement if you want all headers.
            header.append(pandoc.write(elt[-1]).strip())
```

Comment: It seems there's a typo for var in first for loop, `ele` -> `elt`.

Comment: It seems that in pandoc==2.3, pandoc.types doesn't have Header anymore

Answer (score -1):

One could also try to configure pandoc to do that for us. Here's what the manual has to say about the `--shift-heading-level-by` option:

> `--shift-heading-level-by=`*NUMBER*
>
> Shift heading levels by a positive or negative integer.
> For example, with `--shift-heading-level-by=-1`, level 2
> headings become level 1 headings, and level 3 headings
> become level 2 headings.  Headings cannot have a level
> less than 1, so a heading that would be shifted below level 1
> becomes a regular paragraph.  Exception: with a shift of -N,
> a level-N heading at the beginning of the document
> replaces the metadata title. `--shift-heading-level-by=-1`
> is a good choice when converting HTML or Markdown documents that
> use an initial level-1 heading for the document title and
> level-2+ headings for sections. `--shift-heading-level-by=1`
> may be a good choice for converting Markdown documents that
> use level-1 headings for sections to HTML, since pandoc uses
> a level-1 heading to render the document title.

So running pandoc with `--shift-heading-level-by=-1` might be enough to suit your needs.

Comment: Nope. These markdown files are outside of any pandoc management, I want to only get h1 from markdown content via python's pandoc lib. What I would do with that is outside of pandoc scope. The point here is to extract something from markdown content and use it for whatever purpose inside python.